# Erratic localization behavior of GNU gettext compared to strftime or printf

Tags: c, localization, gettext

I am trying to figure out why GNU gettext's behavior is not like `strftime` or `printf` when it comes to localization. I read the entire manual from A to Z but the examples are rather simple. I have cut down the issue to a simple C program.

The task is to switch the locale in the application by user input to receive localized file output.

My locale:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Consider this C sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "my-i18n.h"

#define PI acos(-1.0)

static char *locales[] = {
        "de_DE.UTF-8",
        "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        "he_IL.UTF-8",
        "es_ES.UTF-8",
        "C",
};

void localize(char *locale, struct tm *time) {
        printf("==============================================================\n");
        printf("Passed locale: %s\n", locale);
        char *setlocale_out = setlocale(LC_ALL, locale);
        printf("Set locale: %s\n", setlocale_out);

        char buffer[80];
        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", time);
        printf("Localized time: %s\n", buffer);

        printf("Get rational, π: %f\n", PI);

        printf(_("Hello World!\n"));
        printf(_("Goodbye!\n"));
}

int main(void) {
        time_t rawtime = time(NULL);
        struct tm *time;
        localtime(&rawtime);
        time = localtime(&rawtime);

        bindtextdomain("my-i18n", LOCALEDIR);
        textdomain("my-i18n");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(locales)/sizeof(locales[0]); i++) {
                localize(locales[i], time);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and its output:

```
==============================================================
Passed locale: de_DE.UTF-8
Set locale: de_DE.UTF-8
Localized time: Fr 28 Okt 11:44:24 2016
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
==============================================================
Passed locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
Set locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
Localized time: пятница, 28 октября 2016 г. 11:44:24
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
==============================================================
Passed locale: he_IL.UTF-8
Set locale: he_IL.UTF-8
Localized time: CEST 11:44:24 2016 אוק 28 ו'
Get rational, π: 3.141593
Setting LANG=he_IL.UTF-8
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
==============================================================
Passed locale: es_ES.UTF-8
Set locale: es_ES.UTF-8
Localized time: vie 28 oct 11:44:24 2016
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
==============================================================
Passed locale: C
Set locale: C
Localized time: Fri Oct 28 11:44:24 2016
Get rational, π: 3.141593
Setting LANG=C
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
```

As you can see, `strftime` and `printf` did exactly what I expected, but gettext takes only my external locale into account. After a Google and SO search I have figured out that `bindtextdomain` and/or `textdomain` have to be executed after every `setlocale`. Moreover, I have to perform `putenv("LANG=...")` to force gettext to work.

Modified C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "my-i18n.h"

#define PI acos(-1.0)

static char *locales[] = {
        "de_DE.UTF-8",
        "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        "he_IL.UTF-8",
        "es_ES.UTF-8",
        "C",
};

void localize(char *locale, struct tm *time) {
        printf("==============================================================\n");
        printf("Passed locale: %s\n", locale);
        char *setlocale_out = setlocale(LC_ALL, locale);
        printf("Set locale: %s\n", setlocale_out);

        char buffer[80];
        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", time);
        printf("Localized time: %s\n", buffer);

        printf("Get rational, π: %f\n", PI);

        printf("Setting LANG=%s\n", locale); 
        setenv("LANG", locale, 1);

        bindtextdomain("my-i18n", LOCALEDIR);
        textdomain("my-i18n");
        printf(_("Hello World!\n"));
        printf(_("Goodbye!\n"));
}

int main(void) {
        time_t rawtime = time(NULL);
        struct tm *time;
        localtime(&rawtime);
        time = localtime(&rawtime);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(locales)/sizeof(locales[0]); i++) {
                localize(locales[i], time);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the output:

```
==============================================================
Passed locale: de_DE.UTF-8
Set locale: de_DE.UTF-8
Localized time: Fr 28 Okt 11:50:33 2016
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
Hallo Welt!
Tschüß!
==============================================================
Passed locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
Set locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
Localized time: пятница, 28 октября 2016 г. 11:50:33
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
Привет мир!
Пока!
==============================================================
Passed locale: he_IL.UTF-8
Set locale: he_IL.UTF-8
Localized time: CEST 11:50:33 2016 אוק 28 ו'
Get rational, π: 3.141593
Setting LANG=he_IL.UTF-8
Hello World!
Goodbye!
==============================================================
Passed locale: es_ES.UTF-8
Set locale: es_ES.UTF-8
Localized time: vie 28 oct 11:50:33 2016
Get rational, π: 3,141593
Setting LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
¡Hola mundo!
¡Adios!
==============================================================
Passed locale: C
Set locale: C
Localized time: Fri Oct 28 11:50:33 2016
Get rational, π: 3.141593
Setting LANG=C
Hello World!
Goodbye!
```

Can someone explain this "weird" behavior?

Edit: I have raised it on the mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gettext/2016-11/msg00002.html

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you need to call [`bindtextdomain()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bindtextdomain.3.html) after a [`setlocale()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) call, is *caching*.

If each [`gettext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) call were to check the environment variables, it would be quite slow. Perhaps it would not be noticeable with todays machines, but it used to matter quite a lot. Instead, the (locale) lookup is done when you issue the `bindtextdomain()` call, and the results cached, for efficiency.

In practice, there are .. warts. In particular, the `LANGUAGE` environment variable affects each `gettext()` call. Also, gettext does <strike>not</strike> support thread-specific locales (via [`uselocale()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uselocale.3.html) GNU extension) -- in Linux, when using glibc 2.4 or later (released in 2006), and in macOS/Mac OSX since 2013 or thereabouts. (Edited: I started using gettext way before that, and just failed to keep up to date; I made *assumptions* I should not have. Apologies.) Since the initial release of gettext was back in 1990, and a lot of stuff has changed between then and now, you could just as well consider this historical baggage, or even a bug.

Comment: Hm..but what about `putenv`. Even with `bindtextdomain` it does not work if `putenv` is not called. The documentation isn't really helpful about it.

Comment: @Michael-O: I think it is a bug; I vaguely remember seeing some discussion about it somewhere a few years ago (maybe [bug-gettext](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gettext/) mailing list, or a musl mailing list), related to those practical warts I mentioned. By the way, why not use `setenv("LANG", locale, 1)` instead of `putenv()`?

Comment: it was just sample code I have found on SO. I will change my question. Thank you.

Comment: Is your recommendation to write to the mailing list?

Comment: No, not really, because the sequence `setenv("LANG", locale, 1); setlocale("LC_ALL", locale); bindtextdomain(...); textdomain(...);` is known to work, and is what applications currently do if they need to change locales. If you need thread-specific locale support, you'd need to reimplement the low-level parts of gettext() anyway; it is unlikely to be implemented in gettext any time soon, due to the long history and cross-platform-ness of the project.

Comment: @NominalAninal, all applications are sequential, `uselocale` is not necessary. My question was rather, why is does gettext require me to perform `setenv`. If this is legacy, it should be documented. If not, it is a bug.

Comment: gettext **does** support thread-specific locales (set via `uselocale`) on glibc and macOS systems. Two unit tests in the GNU gettext source code (gettext-6, gettext-7) verify that this works.

Comment: @BrunoHaible: Thanks for the correction; I'll take your word for it -- you wrote those tests, after all -- and shall fix my answer regarding that. Your message on 2006-06-14 to bug-gnu-utils mailing list says this should work in Linux using glibc 2.4 and later (i.e. since 2006); other than changes adding MacOS support to the tests in 2009, I didn't find info on when the release adding mac support landed. If 2009 is incorrect, let me know (or just edit this answer yourself).

Comment: The GNU gettext release that added the proper macOS support was version 0.18.3 (July 2013).